# Find Xpath of W3C Dom Nodes in Java

Tags: java, dom, webview, w3c

I want to find/generate Xpath of Nodes/Element of W3C DOM in Java. I am using JOOX library: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOX
 with this code:

```
String xpath = $(element).xpath();
```

But the xpath given by this code works for some sites and doesnt work for some sites.

Comment: "But the xpath given by this code works for some sites and doesnt work for some sites." which sites? Doesn't work for what?

Comment: it works for twitter github and doesnt work for google

Comment: And what is it that you're doing, that either works or doesn't work?

Comment: this is the xpath generated by the code "/html[1]/body[1]/center[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/div[1]/input[1]" it is for google main input field but it doesnt work.

Comment: actually i want to generate selenium scripts for automated testing

Comment: Selenium simulates a browser. jOOX doesn't. They can't be used together, but for the completely static parts of a webpage... And Google has no such thing. It's weird enough that you managed to get anywhere with Twitter.

Comment: that is the next part to automate 1st i want to extract the xpaths

Comment: If one thing exists in world A and doesn't in world B, you can't get its XPath in world A to use it for world B. It's self-contradictory.

Comment: i am not using same xpath for both webs. it gives different for each web component but the issue is sometime the xpath given by it works and sometime does not

Comment: Your definition of "works" is based on whether or not Selenium will accept it, when you obtained the thing you want to work, from jOOX. You're trying to use "the same" XPath for both Selenium and jOOX, which is only possible on a restricted set of constraints that most modern websites won't pass.

Comment: so what should i do? i also check the xpath manually in google chrome console

Comment: What should you do to do what? So far you've been mixing two technologies in a way that cannot make sense. Your goal seems to be to point out to Selenium an element you identified in some automated way. You need to explain what is your reasoning on what it is you're trying to identify. Selenium should offer a way to do that without any need for any external technology.

Comment: forget selenium i just want to extract/generate a valid xpath for elements :)

Comment: because it makes you happy in life to generate valid xpath for webpage elements, just like some of us like to pick flowers in fields, or are you going to do stuff with these valid xpath?